# Javascript Voting Only Once Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, mobile-safari, dreamweaver, vote

I am developing a poll website and I only want voters to vote once. This is a 3 stage process. The first page is select the person you want to vote for the second page is confirming the person (hidden radio button to submit vote) and the third is a Thank You page. I want to check for the cookie on the first and second pages and write the cookie on the third page. I want the cookie to expire in two days from first navigating to the site. I would like to redirect people who already voted to cookie.htm (in the same folder as everything else) How would you do this?

Comment: That's nice. I want a beer and a hamburger. What's the question?

Comment: I would suggest you to use server side for this task (IP address based). Setting and reading is not very reliable as user can clear cookie and vote again.

Comment: This is going to be used as an iPhone poll for a singing competition at my school. The time for voting will be five minutes. I just want to try to stop the people from voting again. I cant do IP because all of the iPhones/iPod Touches will be connected to the same hotspot (approx. 500 devices).

Answer (score 0):

I think basing it on something like an e-mail address from a known site, with the requirement that someone confirm the email address is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to have a signup process and enforce user login to vote. As mentioned in the comments, you'll need some server side magic.

Comment: The thing is that it will be used for a one time use so there is really  no use/time for a signup/login

Comment: Well then you can't guarantee that a user will only vote once. What if I clear my cookies?

Comment: the site will be used on an iPhone and besides the demographic probably does not know how to clear cookies and let alone know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

To set a cookie using Javascript, set the `document.cookie` object to a string value in the format `[cookiename]=[cookievalue];expires=[expirydate]`.  In this case, it seems like you just need to set a cookie, any cookie, so maybe just "done=true" or whatever.

```
// get today's date plus 2 days
var expiration = new Date();
expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate() + 2);

// add cookie "done=true" with expiration
document.cookie="done=true;expires=" + expiration.toUTCString();
```

To check if a cookie is already set, use `document.cookie` again, which will return a semicolon-delimited list of all cookies.  Filter it to find yours:

```
var myCookie = document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(item) { 
    return item.split('=')[0] == 'done'; 
});
```

If the cookie is set, then you can do a simple redirect:

```
if (myCookie.length > 0) {
    window.location = "cookie.htm";
}
```

See MDN for further [info on cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie).

---

<sub>**Obligatory disclaimer**:  obviously -- as others have noted -- using this approach, users will be able to cheat if they care to, as anyone can just clear their cookies and bypass the check.  Even if you think no one would bother, it might be wise just to add a "sanity check" on the server, and block any IP address that's voted more that X times.</sub>